# Digital Time Delay Relay Dual LED Display 220V AC

Tags: power-connector

I am having trouble in connection.

So basically in S1 and S2 have no power output, the load circuit must be connected to the power.

Can someone give me any solution if i can connect the power supply that i use for the Life wire and Neutral wire to S1 and S2 to power my load

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing the specification of the switch inside the unit. Does the thing come with an instruction manual?

Comment: I did not get any instruction manual from supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to this problem. There I state that I have a connection problem of a power supply with my timer and load.

Solution:

1. It is very simple connection, by connecting the live wire from
   terminal power supply and using wire splitter to split two wire and
   connect live wire to live terminal board and S1 terminal.
2. Connecting the neutral wire from terminal power supply and use
   splitter wire to connect the neutral terminal board and one of the
   wires from the load.
3. Connecting another wire from the load to S2